# yahooFinance module with sapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sapper

I am making a project where I want to use darta from yahooFinance.
I have found this project https://www.npmjs.com/package/yahoo-finance.
I have also used the basic sapper template.

Basically what I am trying is to retrive data from YF and show them on the FE.

I gave this piece of code:

```
<script>
  import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance';
  let response;
  async function searchStock (){
    yahooFinance.historical({
      symbol: 'AAPL',
      from: '2020-01-01',
      to: '2020-12-31',
    }, function (err, quotes) {
      console.log(quotes)
    });
  }
</script>
```

But everytime I try to compile I get:
Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
1: {
2:   "version": "2020d",
^
3:   "zones": [
4:     "Africa/Abidjan|LMT GMT|g.8 0|01|-2ldXH.Q|48e5",

So I gave tried to import it thus way `var yahooFinance = require('yahoo-finance');`

But then I get Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined in to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `yahoo-finance` package on the front end, since it uses Node APIs. Since you're using Sapper, you can use the package in a [server route](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Server_routes) and fetch it from the client.

Create the file `yahoo.json.js` and place it in `src/routes`. Then copy + paste the following into it. This will call the `historical` method from `yahoo-finance` and return the result as JSON.

```
import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance';

export async function get(req, res, next) {
  const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    yahooFinance.historical({
      symbol: 'AAPL',
      from: '2020-01-01',
      to: '2020-12-31',
    }, function (err, quotes) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(quotes);
    });
  })

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

You can then call this server route from within a Svelte component. This uses the Sapper [preload method](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading) to fetch the data before the page renders.

```
<script context="module">
  export async function preload() {
    const res = await this.fetch('/yahoo.json');
    const data = await res.json();

    return {data};
  }

</script>

<script>
  export let data;
</script>

{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

You will likely want to enhance the server route to add request parameters and better error handling, but this shows you how to get it working.